# can't connect to postgresql database "database doesn´t exist"

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I have a Go app that connects with a postgres database through the driver called "github.com/lib/pq".

I make a connection with a database called godb, and the function `Open()` works correctly, but when I check errors with `db.Ping()`, it tells me the database doesn´t exist, although I have created it in pg Admin and the name and the password are well written. I have tried to check if the connection string is correct, I have tried to create a new database and connect it but it gives the same error. I have also tried to disconnect and reconnect the database and it doesn't work.

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"

    //driver of the database
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var (
    db   *sql.DB
    once sync.Once
)

func NewPostgresDB() {
    once.Do(func() {
        var err error

        db, err = sql.Open("postgres",
            "postgres://postgres:/*password of the database*/@localhost:5432/godb?sslmode=disable")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("There is an error in the connction string %v", err)
        }

        if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("There was an error connecting to the database %v", err)
        }
    })

    fmt.Println("connection succeeded")
}
```

this is the error it exactly returns (it's in Spanish):

```sh
pq: no existe la base de datos �godb�
exit status 1
```

Comment: 1. I find it wo seird that your error message contains `�` 2. The error you shown is unlikely to be from the same piece of code you are showing, otherwise it should print something like `There was an error connecting to the database pq: no existe la base de datos �godb�`

Comment: Yea, that´s what it shows completely but I have cut the part that says the same I write in the code. I just wrote what the variable err returns